# How many Hz on resolution of 32767 x 32767?

Tags: display-resolution

If I check with `xrandr` I get the output

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 3200 x 1800, maximum 32767 x 32767
```

which sounds to me, like my graphics card would be able to serve a screen with max 32767 x 32767 px. Is that true? That really sounds a lot!
And how many Hz would I achieve with such a large *futuristic* screen?

Is there a way to calculate the Hz my graphics card would serve max at a 4k or at a 5k resolution?

Or is there a better way to find out the max resolution for my graphics adapter (before buying a monitor)?

Answer (score 0):

Your last question has already been answered.  However to better Demonstrate this next piece.  Grab a CRT monitor, then grab an LCD monitor with only VGA connections.  Then briefly look at Hz for those monitors.  Now, understand that monitors are going to fully depend on what your refresh rate is going to be.  Normally you can override those values in your Graphics Adapters Settings Page; however you get to those, sometimes doesn't matter.

Your adapter is finding the right rate:pixel ratio the monitor can handle, since this is how many times you can refresh a page on the screen every X amount of seconds.

http://modia.com/what-is-refresh-rate.aspx is a more detailed understanding of what my question just answered.  Remember that components work together, if one is batting under 300 then so will everything else that uses said component.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. Can my graphics card serve any monitor? It seems like the max resolution is 32.000 px???

Comment: Yes it answers it very well. You're card can only refresh as much as your monitor can. As long as your graphics card can attach to the monitor without use of converters, yes your gfx card can.

Comment: But I didn't get any monitor by now. My main question is, can I buy a 4k monitor or maybe a 5k monitor and how can I find out BEFORE I have it?